# PostgreSQL - Adding "constraint" to view

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have tried to add a way in can_graduate that checks if the person has read enough sum_credits (180) to graduate and I'm wondering if someone could help me with that. Where I check that Count(UnreadMandatory) = 0 is where I assume that I wanna add something like sum_credits >= 180 but I can't get it to work.

This is my first post here so please be kind.

This is the view that I'm having trouble with:
https://pastebin.com/ezUtRMGB

```
    CREATE VIEW PathToGraduation AS
    SELECT student.national_ID,

    (SELECT sum(passedcourses.credit)
    FROM passedcourses, has_classification
    WHERE passedcourses.national_ID = student.national_ID AND has_classification.code = passedcourses.code) AS sum_credits,

    (SELECT count(UnreadMandatory)
    FROM UnreadMandatory
    WHERE UnreadMandatory.national_ID = student.national_ID) AS remaining_courses,

    (SELECT sum(passedcourses.credit)
    FROM passedcourses, has_classification
    WHERE passedcourses.national_ID = student.national_ID AND has_classification.code = passedcourses.code AND has_classification.type = 'Math_class') AS math_credits,

    (SELECT count(passedcourses.credit)
    FROM passedcourses, has_classification
    WHERE passedcourses.national_ID = student.national_ID AND has_classification.code = passedcourses.code AND has_classification.type = 'Seminar_class') AS seminar_courses_taken,

    (SELECT count(passedcourses.code)
    FROM passedcourses, has_classification
    WHERE passedcourses.national_ID = student.national_ID AND has_classification.code = passedcourses.code AND has_classification.type = 'Research_class') AS research_credits,

    (SELECT 'YES' AS can_graduate
    FROM UnreadMandatory
    WHERE student.national_ID = UnreadMandatory.national_ID
    HAVING COUNT(UnreadMandatory) = 0
    UNION
    (SELECT 'NO' AS can_graduate
    FROM UnreadMandatory
    WHERE student.national_ID = UnreadMandatory.national_ID
    HAVING COUNT(UnreadMandatory) != 0))
```

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for `WITH CHECK OPTION` .

As per documentation.

> This option controls the behavior of automatically updatable views.
>   When this option is specified, INSERT and UPDATE commands on the view
>   will be checked to ensure that new rows satisfy the view-defining
>   condition (that is, the new rows are checked to ensure that they are
>   visible through the view). If they are not, the update will be
>   rejected. If the CHECK OPTION is not specified, INSERT and UPDATE
>   commands on the view are allowed to create rows that are not visible
>   through the view.

[**CREATE VIEW**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-createview.html)

Comment: Not sure how that's gonna solve my problem.
The problem is that my can_graduate can't see sum_credits